# What are the differences between EventEmitter, EventTarget and EventDispatcher

Tags: observer-pattern, eventemitter, event-dispatching

I'm trying to learn implementations of Observer Pattern.

EventEmitter/EventTarget/EventDispatcher are one implementation of Observer Pattern but I wonder the differences between these three.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily find documentation about all of them I think:

- [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) - quite simple implementation to use in browsers
- [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) - native nodejs implemetation, rich on functionality
- [EventDispatcher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) - one of many implementations, used mostly in PHP

Answer (score 2):

I would like to mention a detail difference when adding the same listener.

EventEmitter:

```js
const EventEmitter = require('node:events')

const foo = new EventEmitter()
foo.on('event', listener)
foo.on('event', listener)
foo.emit('event')
// called: 1
// called: 2

function listener() {
  console.count('called')
}
```

EventTarget:

```js
const foo = new EventTarget()
foo.addEventListener('event', listener)
foo.addEventListener('event', listener)
foo.dispatchEvent(new Event('event'))
// called: 1

function listener() {
  console.count('called')
}

// ------

const foo = new EventTarget()
foo.addEventListener('event', listener, { once: true })
foo.addEventListener('event', listener)
foo.dispatchEvent(new Event('event'))
foo.dispatchEvent(new Event('event'))
// called: 1

function listener() {
  console.count('called')
}

// -----

const foo = new EventTarget()
foo.addEventListener('event', listener)
foo.addEventListener('event', listener, { once: true })
foo.dispatchEvent(new Event('event'))
foo.dispatchEvent(new Event('event'))
// called: 1
// called: 2

function listener() {
  console.count('called')
}
```